# AutoHotKey Warning: This variable appears to never be assigned a value

Tags: autohotkey

```
#SingleInstance Prompt

global WinGet, WindowList, List

; Get a list of all open windows
WinGet WindowList, List

; Loop through the list and display information about each window
Loop % WindowList %
{
     ; Get the window title and process name
     this_id := WindowList%A_Index%
     WinGetTitle Title, % "ahk_id " % this_id
     WinGet ProcessName, ProcessName, % "ahk_id " % this_id

     ; Display information
     MsgBox Window %A_Index% `nTitle  %Title%`nProcess %ProcessName%
}
```

gives

[image]

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: The answers don't seem to mention actual problem clearly, which is this line `global WinGet, WindowList, List` What is up with that line and why do you have it? Based off the code you're providing it doesn't seem to serve any purpose, and in the case of `WinGet` and `List` it's even plain wrong (`WinGet` is a command and `List` is an argument to the command!). AHK is smart enough to understand that the line `WinGet WindowList, List` is using the command `WinGet` instead of that super global variable you declare and therefore the super global goes unused, hence the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AutoHotkey v1:**

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#SingleInstance Prompt

; Get a list of all open windows
WinGet, id, list,,, Program Manager

; Loop through the list and display information about each window
Loop, %id%
{
     ; Get the window title and process name
     this_ID := id%A_Index%
     WinGetTitle Title, ahk_id %this_ID%
     WinGet ProcessName, ProcessName, ahk_id %this_ID%
     
     ; Display information
     MsgBox Window %A_Index% `nTitle:  %Title%`nProcess:  %ProcessName%
}
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinGet.htm

**AutoHotkey v2:**

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#SingleInstance Prompt

; Get a list of all open windows
ids := WinGetList(,, "Program Manager")
for this_id in ids
{
   ; Get the window title and process name
   title := WinGetTitle(this_id)
   ProcessName := WinGetProcessName(this_id)
    
   ; Display information
   MsgBox("Window " A_Index "`nTitle: "  title "`nProcessName: "  ProcessName)
}
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/WinGetList.htm